# How to get the ID of the link in another page in php

Tags: php, mysql

I like to catch the id of below  tag in show.php file 
once the link is clicked... I have already got the href name in show.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
  $choice=$_GET['prod'];

  $dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','online_shopping') or die('Connection Error');

  $query1="SELECT name, id from ".$choice; $result1=mysqli_query($dbc,$query1) or die('Error querying Database');

  echo "<h1>List of available products in your category</h1><hr>"; 

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) { 
    $id=$row['id'];
?>
<a style="font-size:18px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; color:#09F;" href="show.php?ref=<?php echo $row['name'];?>" id="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $id;echo '.'.$row['name']; echo '</a>';
```

Comment: I think your mixing up server side and client side code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute is only used client side, so short of using JavaScript to modify the URL — you can't.

Put the data in the URL in the first place … and exercise some safety over adding data to URLs and HTML.

```
<a href="show.php?ref=<?php 
  echo htmlspecialchars(urlencode($row['name']));
?>&id=<?php 
  echo htmlspecialchars(urlencode($id));
?>" 
id="<?php 
  echo htmlspecialchars($id);
?>"><?php 
  echo htmlspecialchars($id) . '.' . htmlspecialchars($row['name']); 
?></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're looking for `$_GET`.

```
<?php

   //show.php?ref=5&id=10

   echo $_GET['ref'];
   //5

   echo $_GET['id'];
   //10

?>
```

Comment: @Bright Please post more code in your question. It's difficult to guess what isn't working.

Comment: <?php
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{


$choice=$_GET['prod'];

$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','online_shopping') or die('Connection Error');
$query1="SELECT name, id from ".$choice;
$result1=mysqli_query($dbc,$query1) or die('Error querying Database');echo "<h1>List of available products in your category</h1><hr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
 $id=$row['id'];
 
 
?><a style="font-size:18px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; color:#09F;"

href="show.php?ref=<?php echo $row['name'];?>" 

id="<?php echo $id;?>">
<?php echo $id;echo '.'.$row['name'];
echo '</a>';

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>
```